# Ubuntu and Firefox can't load a specific webpage

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, ubuntu-9.10

Firefox is completely unable to load twitter.com when I am using my Ubuntu Karmic partition.  The tab just says "Loading" for minutes until it reports that the site has timed out.  All other websites I use work just fine.

I can ping the site just fine

The same computer but using the windows partition loads twitter.com fine.  Other computers on the network using either windows or karmic also load the site just fine.

Comment: sounds funny, have this happened for a long time? the other day i have somewhat similar problem, but it disappeared

Comment: Have you tried with Konqueror, Opera, wget, cURL? Does any of those connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your /etc/hosts file and look for a record for twitter.com.

If there is one, remove it, and try again.

Comment: Now I feel like dork.  I set a local ip for twitter while at rails camp uk and forgot all about it.  Doh!

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometimes, on various sites. Something with the cookie that authenticates you. Try right-clicking the page, Page Info -> Privacy tab and click the 'view cookies' button. delete all the twitter cookies and reload.